# In probability, does Pr($A|B$) + Pr($A^c|B$) = 1?

Tags: probability

I know that for an event $B$, we have Pr($B$) + Pr($B^c$) = 1. But when dealing with conditional probability, how am I to deal with this knowledge? For example, consider this example. Let event $A$ be the probability of coming first in a race, and let event $B$ be if it's raining outside.

It seems that it should be that

$$Pr(A=First Place|B=Raining) + Pr(A=Not First Place|B=Raining) = 1$$

My argument for this is that if both terms have the same condition, then you can really just ignore the condition. Why? Because instead, for example, let $C$ be if I am human, which is trivially true. Then

$$Pr(A=First Place) + Pr(A=Not First Place) $$

$$= Pr(A=First Place|C=Human) + Pr(A=Not First Place|C=Human) $$

$$= 1. $$

I can add on any other trivial condition and it will still be true, I argue. And therefore just consider if it's raining or not as a trivial condition.

Comment: Please use the `\Pr` and `\text{ }` commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation is true and your interpretation seems reasonable to me.  If you want to confirm it algebraically, start with the definition:
$$\eqalign{P(A|B)+P(A^c|B)
  &=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}+\frac{P(A^c\cap B)}{P(B)}\cr
  &=\frac{P(A\cap B)+P(A^c\cap B)}{P(B)}\ .\cr}$$
Now the events $A\cap B$ and $A^c\cap B$ are mutually exclusive, so
$$P(A\cap B)+P(A^c\cap B)=P((A\cap B)\cup(A^c\cap B))=P(B)$$
and the proof is complete.